# looking for easy tool for users to provide feedback directly on a website

Tags: wordpress

I need to help a non technical friend living overseas to fix a site thats been poorly built with no up front design, sitemaps etc. They can't use Trello and dont understand the design/feedback process, so I feel the fastest is to use an easy to use collaborative tool that allows him to annotate the website directly (its still in a staging area) and leave comments for developers to work from. If it could integrate with Trello that would be a plus buts not needed.

I have just found products like ProjectHuddle, UserSnap, Bounce, WP Feedback and a few more, but I dont have the time to install and test them all due to the deadline to finish the site

Has anyone used any of these and can recommend them, for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

From the description, and it being a non technical person, I feel the fastest and easiest way may be to utilize Microsoft's product line. Using Microsoft Teams and White Board specifically.

The way I am envisioning is to create a "whiteboard" (its a microsoft app) on the computer then have him or someone else take screen capture of a website's page. With whiteboard he can highlight or circle the area that needs to be edited. And in Microsoft Teams chat window, he can request edits. You could also integrate Trello into it, however, you would need to state how you want it to integrate so I can see if your preferred method works.

There is alternatively Microsoft Planner that can be used instead of Trello which you can upload the image to tasks. Don't know if trello has that ability.

If he is severely non tech savvy, if can do a meeting with him over the internet, you can setup the whiteboard from Microsoft Teams add the picture yourself, and then let him make the annotations on the picture.

We can give a free demonstration if it sounds like this may fix your issue.